# How to calculate days difference between two NSDate objects in different time zones?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have two NSDate which are initiated from UTC dates.
Lets call them (A & B)

I know that the A represents a day in China and B represents a day in USA. (I know the time zones.) How can I calculate the difference in days between the two...?

I have been using the following method which is obviously incorrect.

```
class func daysDifferenceIn(firstDate: NSDate, firstTimeZone: String, secondDate: NSDate, secondTimeZone: String) -> Int {
    objc_sync_enter(self)

    let firstDateComponents = NSCalendar.CommonCalendar.componentsInTimeZone(NSTimeZone(name: firstTimeZone)!, fromDate: firstDate)
    let secondDateComponents = NSCalendar.CommonCalendar.componentsInTimeZone(NSTimeZone(name: secondTimeZone)!, fromDate: secondDate)
    NSCalendar.CommonCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: firstTimeZone)!
    let firstCalDate = NSCalendar.CommonCalendar.dateFromComponents(firstDateComponents)
    NSCalendar.CommonCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: secondTimeZone)!
    let secondCalDate = NSCalendar.CommonCalendar.dateFromComponents(secondDateComponents)
    objc_sync_exit(self)

    return firstCalDate!.numberOfDaysUntilDateTime(secondCalDate!)
}

func numberOfDaysUntilDateTime(toDateTime: NSDate, inTimeZone timeZone: NSTimeZone? = nil) -> Int {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.CommonCalendar
    if let timeZone = timeZone {
        calendar.timeZone = timeZone
    }

    var fromDate: NSDate?, toDate: NSDate?

    calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, startDate: &fromDate, interval: nil, forDate: self)
    calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, startDate: &toDate, interval: nil, forDate: toDateTime)

    let difference = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: fromDate!, toDate: toDate!, options: [])

    return difference.day
}
```

I can manually subtract day components from `firstDateComponents` and `secondDateComponents` which I don't want to do as I have to look for edge cases of 31 and 28 and so on.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

First date is 2017-02-10 16:15:00 +0000
Second date is  2017-02-11 03:20:00 +0000 Both are UTC.

firstTimeZone   String  "Asia/Shanghai"
secondTimeZone  String  "America/Los_Angeles"

So the day difference is -1 Day. Basically I am implementing flight status and you can see the following link as the flight lands 1 day prior to take day. As it flies from West to East.

https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ua+890

Also a description of Date components.

```
Printing description of firstDateComponents:
<NSDateComponents: 0x600000142310>
    Calendar: <CFCalendar 0x60000088b6d0 [0x10c5d3df0]>{identifier = 'gregorian'}
    TimeZone: Asia/Shanghai (GMT+8) offset 28800
    Era: 1
    Calendar Year: 2017
    Month: 2
    Leap month: no
    Day: 11
    Hour: 0
    Minute: 15
    Second: 0
    Nanosecond: 0
    Quarter: 0
    Year for Week of Year: 2017
    Week of Year: 6
    Week of Month: 2
    Weekday: 7
    Weekday Ordinal: 2
Printing description of secondDateComponents:
<NSDateComponents: 0x60000014b8f0>
    Calendar: <CFCalendar 0x60000049b620 [0x10c5d3df0]>{identifier = 'gregorian'}
    TimeZone: America/Los_Angeles (PST) offset -28800
    Era: 1
    Calendar Year: 2017
    Month: 2
    Leap month: no
    Day: 10
    Hour: 19
    Minute: 20
    Second: 0
    Nanosecond: 0
    Quarter: 0
    Year for Week of Year: 2017
    Week of Year: 6
    Week of Month: 2
    Weekday: 6
    Weekday Ordinal: 2
```

Comment: What result would you expect if the two dates are on the same day in China but on different days in the US?

Comment: @MartinR You can see my update to the question.

Comment: Related: [NSDate for the same local time as another NSDate in different time zones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38282732)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Indeed. Having read the question now multiple times, that seems be be what really wanted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an odd case. You're looking for the difference in calendar dates between two Dates when those dates are evaluated in a specific time zone.

I did some playing, and came up with code that works for dates that fall in the same year:

```
let date = Date()

guard let nycTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST"),
  let nzTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "NZDT") else {
    fatalError()
}
var nycCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nycCalendar.timeZone = nycTimeZone
var nzCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nzCalendar.timeZone = nzTimeZone

let now = Date()

let nycDayOfYear = nycCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: now)

var nzDayOfYear = nzCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: now)
```

I'm using New York and Aukland, NZ as my time zones because as of the time of this writing, those zones are on different dates.

As of now (~12:00 PM on Feb 11, 2017 in US Eastern Standard Time (UTC - 5) the code above gives

```
nycDayOfYear = 42
```

and

```
nzDayOfYear = 43
```

It would take some work to make that calculation work across year boundaries.

Curiously, the following code:

```
var nzDayOfEra = nzCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: now)
let nycDayOfEra = nycCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: now)
```

Gives the same value for both NZ and NYC. I'm not sure why.

### EDIT:

Ok, I did some experimenting and got code that works. What I do is to convert both dates to month/day/year date components using a calendar set to the local time zone for each time. Then I use a method `dateComponents(_:from:to:)` to calculate the difference between those 2 `DateComponents`, in days:

```
import UIKit

let date = Date()

guard let nycTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST"),
  let nzTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "NZDT") else {
    fatalError()
}
var nycCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nycCalendar.timeZone = nycTimeZone
var nzCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
nzCalendar.timeZone = nzTimeZone

let now = Date()


let nycDateComponents = nycCalendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: now)
let nzDateComponents = nzCalendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: now)

let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day],
  from: nycDateComponents,
    to: nzDateComponents)

let daysDifference = difference.days
```

As of this writing that gives a daysDifference of 1. Since we're using the  `dateComponents(_:from:to:)` function, it takes care of the math to calculate the number of days difference between the 2 month/day/year `DateComponents`.

Comment: It is helpful, but I am looking for more full proof answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I added code that gives you the answer you need.

Comment: I also posted an answer and someone down voted without any comments. Your solution is also good. Do you see anything wrong with my answer in which I took hints from your code... ?

Comment: See my comment on your answer. I got wrong results trying to use era-based calculations.

Comment: What you are actually doing is taking two dates and getting the difference between them in respect to the local time zone. The first thing you did was to remove the time zone information... This is exactly the result you would get if you had two datetime strings (including the timezone) and parsed them to your local time zone and then got the number of days between them.

Comment: @sulthan, Why would calculating the number of days in the .era ordinal strip out the time zone information? I Would expect it to give answers that reflect the difference in time zones. If you use an `in:` value of `.year`, you get the desired result, at least when both dates fall in the same year in their local time zone. See the edit to my answer that provides a working solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A `NSDate` represents a moment in time. It has no time zone. Only string representations of dates have time zone information.

If you have the dates, just take the number of days between them. Don't worry about time zones.

Usually:

```
let difference = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: self, toDate: toDate!, options: [])
return difference.day
```

should be enough.

Comment: Minor nitpicking: *"just take the number of days ... Don't worry about time zones"* *may* be misleading. The difference in days makes only sense with respect to a calendar and a time zone. That can of course be the default calendar and the local time zone.

Comment: @Sulthan you can look at my Update to the question.

Comment: "Only string representations of dates have time zone information." No, that's not exactly true. Consider converting an `NSDate` to `DateComponents`. The year/month/day/hour/minute values you get will be different depending on time zone. The expression of a Date object in a particular calendar depends on the time zone, regardless of wether that representation is numeric or string-based.

Comment: The OP is asking about an unusual problem: Figuring out the difference in calendar dates for 2 different locations on earth that are in different time zones. For example, right now it's Feb 13th in Aukland, NZ, but Feb 12th in New York City. The OP wants a result of 1 day difference in that case. He **WANTS** to worry about time zones.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't think that's an unusual problem. I think that's an impossible problem. While we could devise a solution, that solution would have too many edge cases.

Comment: @Sulthan, see the edit to my answer. I found fairly simple working code that lets the Calendar object deal with all the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `let interval = laterDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(earlierDate)`? This will return the difference between the two dates in seconds.